# How to create a second splash screen (after default splash screen in ios)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, splash-screen

I tried to add a second splash screen to iOS existing project, this project was too old and using xib's.

So i was planning to show default splash screen first and then my own one image as splash screen after that login page.

This is what i have done so far

In my `ViewController.m` file i have created on `UIView` and added one `UIImageView` its working but the problem is i can see navigationbar also along with second splash screen .

I dont want that navigation bar.

Please help me
Code

```
ViewController.m   in ViewDidload ()



 self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;

    _splash.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
    _splashImg.frame=_splash.frame;
    [self.view insertSubview:_splash aboveSubview:_loginView];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0f target:self selector:@selector(runMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:_splashView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_splashView];
    UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rss2.png"]];
    img.frame=_splashView.frame;
    [_splashView addSubview:img];
```

Comment: Why are you add as a Navigation controller's root view controller.

Comment: Please refer my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

To hide the navigation bar:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

To show it:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

else

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];   //it hides
```

}

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];    // it shows
 }
```

Comment: you can directly place the image to self.view why you take the too much of frames

Comment: still i can see navigationbar

Answer (score 2):

Apple allows only one splash screen per project. You can show your custom image as a splash by creating a new view controller. Say **SplashViewController**. Add an imageView on SplashViewController's view and set your splash image.

Load **SplashViewController** when you want to show your custom splash.

In SplashViewController's ViewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [self performSelector:@selector(loadingNextView) 
           withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0f];
}
```

method to load next view

```
- (void)loadingNextView{
// write code for pushing VC. 
}
```

In your next view controller's ViewDidLoad show navigation bar

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: my issue is with navigationbar

Comment: you can show and hide navigation bar according to your need. Check my updated answer.

Comment: will you show me what you did in application:didfinishlaunching ?

Comment: How did you create navigationController. by code or in storyboard. Also please share your code to pushing a ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no 'official' way to have a second splash screen, so what you're doing is the way to go. The only suggestion I have for you is to add your custom splash screen view to a **window** instead of the view controller's view. Adding it to the window (and sizing it accordingly) will make your custom view stand above everything else. You might even create a new window and place it at the UIStatusBar level for a similar, cleaner, effect.

**Edit: adding sample code**

For the simplest solution

```
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window;
_splash.frame = window.bounds;
[window addSubview:_splash];
...
// later, when you're done
[_splash removeFromSuperview];
```

For the slightly more complex, but more elegant, solution of creating a new window, please read the [UIWindow documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/).

Answer (score 1):

In the `AppDelegate` You set the navigation controller as a root view controller in that replace with you just do create the UIViewController as a root `viewcontroller`.

After few second you just do as a `performSelector` thru change the root view controller to navigation controller and your problem has been resolve.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
SplashScreenController *viewCon=[[SplashScreenController alloc]
                                      initWithNibName:@"SplashScreenController"
                                      bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController= viewCon;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[self performSelector:@selector(loadNavigationController) 
           withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2f];
}
-(void)loadNavigationController{
    HomeController *viewCon=[[HomeController alloc]
                                      initWithNibName:@"HomeController"
                                      bundle:nil];

        self.nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewCon];
        self.window.rootViewController= self.nav;
}
```

May this help to ease to solve your problem.